# Is there a way to store JavaScript in a variable and run it?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make a function that runs a specified piece of code forever. How can I do this?

Example:

```
function forever(code) {
   for (let i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
      //Run code from variable here
   }
```

I've tried:

```
function forever(code) {
   for (let i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
      code
   }
```

Comment: `while(true) { }` ?

Comment: Make `code` a function and call it.

Comment: a `while` loop is blocking

Comment: You might want to consider using something like `setInterval` and call the function in some intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `while` loop.

```js
function forever(code) {
  while (true) {
    console.log("Running forever");
  }
}

forever();
```